# Django form make field readonly depending on Boolean field

Tags: python, django, forms, conditional-statements

I have two fields in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    urgency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_days = models.IntegerField(default=20, validators=[MinValueValidator(5), MaxValueValidator(40)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

In my views.py I have:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['urgency', 'date_days']



    def clean_field_1(self):
        if self.instance.urgency:
            return self.instance.date_days
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data.get('date_days')


    def form_valid(self, form): 
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I would like to make field 'date_days' 'readonly' if 'urgency == True', and to enable back again if 'urgency == False'. User can toggle between True/False.

Comment: Do you know you need a bit of JavaScript on template?

Comment: So something like this:
<pre>  ```<script>
            function GFG_Run() {
                document.getElementById('id_urgency').readOnly=true;
                document.getElementById('id_date_days').readOnly=true;
            }
</script>```<code>